# Why my call for access token exchange from authorization code failed?

Tags: oauth-2.0, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I am using the authentication code mode of [Huawei account kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/dev-guide-account-0000001050048888) to login users to my app. To check the app server to account server behavior, I use the cURL command shown bellow to obtain the access token from the authorization code. But the following command would return an error.

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d @body.txt -X POST https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

the "body.txt" file contains the required information for the request:

```
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=DQB6e3x9zFqHIfkHR2ctp7htDs5tG5p6jXTkTCeoAAULtuS69PntuuD9pwqHrdXyvrlezuRc/aq+zuDU7OnQdRpImnvZcEX+RIOijYMXYu1j+zxpQ+W/J50Z7pY1qhyxZtavqkELY+6o2jSifaiIxC/MJc7KgqKV3jGn9kUIEZovSnM&
client_id=my_id&
client_secret=my_secrete&
redirect_uri=hms://redirect_uri
```

The command returns:

```
> POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 430
>
* upload completely sent off: 430 out of 430 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 03:38:21 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 67
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server: elb
<
* Connection #0 to host oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com left intact
{"sub_error":20152,"error_description":"invalid code","error":1101}
```

What should I do to get this API call working using cURL as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication code must be urlencoded before sent. The command in the question used that code without urlencoding non-letter characters. Please use the same command with encoded authorization code as parameter to "code" to perform the request to acquire access token

Encoding could be done inline by if doing so is desired
curl --data-urlencode "para1=value1"

Please refer to:  [Link](http://address.of.api.call) or using online tool such as : [Link](https://www.urlencoder.org/)

Using other tools to acquire access token is possible as long as the parameters are properly encoded with %2x format.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error information `{"sub_error":20152,"error_description":"invalid code","error":1101}`, the problem is caused by incorrect code parameters.

It is recommended that you can check whether the value of code in the request is the same as the Authorization Code obtained by the mobile app.

FOR Details,see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/server-error-codes-0000001062371380-V5?ha_source=hms1).

[image]

Comment: Detailed info is very helpful. Thank you.